# Why am I getting this error (unknown tag <:color> )even when there's no such tag in the file?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Everything worked well before I copy-pasted some code from another project. It worked well in that project but here it started showing this error. Even my colors.xml file doesn't contain any such tag.
The error and array.xml

[image: The error and array.xml]

color.xml

[image: color.xml]

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Shift+F` and search for `<:color>`. You will get location where this tag is present in your project.

Comment: Check the code you copy-pasted from another project - the error is probably there in one of the files under res/values/ directory (not necessarily colors.xml, it could be values.xml or styles.xml for example).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by a resource array not containing **item**

The error makes it very confusing :)

```
<string-array name="...">
        <string>...</string>
<string-array name="...">
```

This will result in: `error: unknown tag <:string>.`

Change to

```
<string-array name="...">
        <item>...</item>
<string-array name="...">
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to answer but what I worked for me is changing `<string>` tags into `<item>` under `<string-array>` element.